# Extract an element from a set and count its frequency

Tags: python, count, set, token

I have a set object like this

```
{'Book',
 'car',
 'bird',
 'cup',
 'book',
 ...
 'river'}
```

Since in Python, set object does not support indexing. If I want to extract certain elements, say 'Book' and its lowercase form 'book', from the set and count their frequencies relative to total number of elements (i.e., tokens) in the set. What is the handy way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: `your_set.remove('Book')`

Comment: Wait, hold on. You do realise that the frequency will always be 1, since set elements are unique, right?

Comment: I don't think pop() will work in this context.

Comment: do you need different versions of the same word with a different casing?

Comment: Yes, I am experimenting with both uppercase and lowercase versions of the same word.

Comment: When you say "extract", do you mean you want to remove the word from the set?

Comment: No, I just want to get its frequency in the set.

Comment: Do you only need to deal with (at most) those 2 possibilities, all lower case and capitalized, like 'book' and 'Book'? Or are there other possibilities, like 'BOOK', and even 'bOoK'?

Comment: I haven't moved that far (i.e., same word with different upper and lower case sequence of spelling), but would certainly want to know how to do that.

Comment: I believe you can use [`collelctions.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) to accomplish what your asking. That is, finding the frequency of an element. Realize though that the result will always be `1`.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. They really enlighten me on how to count word frequency in a set object in different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count how many times the word is in the list whatever the casing by couting the occurrences of its lowercased (or casefolded) version (otherwise the question doesn't make sense since `set` guarantees uniqueness) using `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections

s = {'Book',
 'car',
 'bird',
 'cup',
 'book',
 'CuP',
 'river'}

c = collections.Counter(map(str.casefold,s))

print(c)
```

result:

```
Counter({'book': 2, 'cup': 2, 'river': 1, 'car': 1, 'bird': 1})
```

and for frequencies:

```
freq = {k:v/len(s) for k,v in c.items()}  # python 2: needs `float(v)/...`
```

which gives:

```
{'cup': 0.2857142857142857, 'river': 0.14285714285714285, 'car': 0.14285714285714285, 'bird': 0.14285714285714285, 'book': 0.2857142857142857}
```

as explained by a nice comment, [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) handles more cases (no pun intended!) than `str.lower`, even if `str.lower` works for most words (use `str.lower` for Python 2.x, as `casefold` isn't available)

Comment: [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) is probably better for this.

Comment: @PM2Ring that's very interesting.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is probably more what the OP wanted.

Comment: @PM2Ring :) I doubt it, Chris has 90 rep. At this point you're beginning to know how the site works.

Comment: For more fun with `.casefold`, take a look at this crazy thing. ;) [case_insensitive_string.py](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/ddcf20d6014184b8f600bb81ff68286b). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45107228/4014959

Answer (score 1):

This is handy (and it works also for lists) :

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter
mySet = {'Book',
 'car',
 'bird',
 'cup',
 'book',
 'river'}

def Cc(s): # generates all possible cases for a string
  s = s.lower()
  for p in product(*[(0,1)]*len(s)):
    yield ''.join(c.upper() if t else c for t,c in zip(p,s))

elements = list(Cc("book")) # ['book','Book','bOok',....,'BOOK']
counts = Counter(mySet)
avg = sum(counts[e] for e in elements)/len(mySet)
print(avg) # => 0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: The main point of using sets is that they provide very fast membership testing. Whereas the `list.count` method has to perform a linear scan of the list to do its work. And since you're constructing a list from a set, the count for each item can only ever be zero or one. So this technique is _very_ inefficient.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to extract certain elements, say 'Book' and its lowercase form 'book', from the set and count their frequencies relative to total number of elements (i.e., tokens) in the set.

If you want to find the frequency of a certain element in your set, you can use `collections.Counter` to accomplish this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = \
  {'Book',
 'car',
 'bird',
 'cup',
 'book',
 'river'}
>>> c = Counter(s)
>>> c['Book']
1
>>> c['book']
1
>>>
```

Realize however, that `set`s do not support duplicate elements, so the frequency will always be `1`. Consider using a `list` or `tuple` to initialize your `Counter` object.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this to me.

Comment: @ChrisT. Note that this code counts the upper and lower case versions of a word separately. From your question I believe that 
Jean-François Fabre's answer is what you actually want, because it combines the count for all upper / lower case variations of a word.

Answer (score 1):

```
mySet =  {'Book','car','bird','cup','book','river'}

counter = lambda s, element: len([e for e in s if element.lower() == e.lower()])

print(counter(mySet, "Book"))
```

Result:

```
2
```

Comment: That's ok if you just want to test a single word, but since you have to scan & convert the entire set, you might as well save the results so that multiple counts can be performed without having to rescan the set.